# how to fill 3x3 2d array from numbers 1-9

Tags: c++

i know that my question maybe down voted and amateur/basic but I'll take it gladly for the sake of learning. how do i fill my 2d array from numbers 1-9 using loop? no vectors pls, im still in the basic ty.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int ar[3][3]= {0};

    for(int i =1;i<=9;i++){ //this is the part i think im wrong and i cant figure it out

        ar[3][3] = i;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<3; j++){    
        cout<<ar[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: your question has the answer in itself.. can you see below how you are looping through the two indices of the array to print? use the same approach to assign values. just have a counter and increase it for each inner loop and assign the value

Comment: `std::iota(&ar[0][0], &ar[0][0] + 9, 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do it would be just to use a counter with two `for()` loops. You can assign the counter to the location specified by the `for()` loops and then increment the counter. It might look something like this:

```
int counter = 1;
for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        arr[i][j] = counter;
        ++counter;
    }
}
```

Your other option is to explicitly initialize the array when you declare it. You can do this as follows:

```
int array[3][3] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}};
```

Comment: thank you very much. i already thought about the second option that you mention. it's just that im curious on how will i automatically fill it up using loop. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use two nested loops to fill the array, same as for printing it. Use a counter to count from 1 to 9 by incrementing it in the inner loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int ar[3][3];

    int a = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<3; j++){    
            ar[i][j] = a;
            a++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<3; j++){    
            cout<<ar[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```